# TypeError:must be a string without null bytes, not str

Tags: python, typeerror, os.system

I am having trouble passing in a variable to an `os.system` call in python. I have the following code:

```
f1 = open("package.txt","r+")
for i in f1:
    os.system("adb shell dumpsys package %s" %i)
```

and in my `package.txt` I have the following containing inside:

```
com.android.customlocale2
com.android.gallery3d
com.android.calendar
com.android.dialer
com.example.android.apis
com.android.htmlviewer
com.android.location.fused 
com.android.backupconfirm  
jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn 
com.android.packageinstaller
com.cyanogenmod.filemanager
com.android.providers.userdictionary
com.android.providers.downloads.ui
com.android.externalstorage
com.android.providers.contacts
com.android.dreams.phototable
com.android.galaxy4
```

I want to pass in each of the following within the os.system call but I can not unfortunately have it so that it works as intended. When run the code gives me the error

> TypeError:must be string without null bytes, not str

I have looked at other forums/questions on stackoverflow and they say to add an 'r' to the beginning of the `os.system` call but that unfortunately is not working.

Comment: `i` probably ends with `\n`. Try stripping it first: `"adb shell dumpsys package %s" % i.strip()`

Comment: So I tried what you said but im still getting the same error. Could there be another reason for this error?

Comment: Have you tried using the `subprocess` module instead?

Comment: @PaulRooney Never tried the subprocess module, but I'll give it a try

Comment: Try something like this `os.system('cmd.exe /c start '+url404)`

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Print the `repr()` of the string you generate and edit the question to show *exactly* what is being passed to give the error condition.  It should not be hard to generate a one-liner that reproduces your error message. Also, what version of Python are you using?  There's probably a null byte in your input file.